# Can I change Binary from Device into Simulator Build? - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I have an app bundle that which doesn't work on my simulator (because it is builded for Devices)

is there a line or coding I can change inside the (bundle) or something to make it work on my simulator?

Comment: No. You need to do a full build specific to the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change an existing app bundle (built for a device) to work on the simulator.

iOS devices use ARM processors, so an app bundle built for devices contains ARM machine code.  The simulator runs on Macs, and Macs use Intel processors, so an app bundle built for the simulator contains Intel machine code. Apple doesn't ship anything that can translate ARM code into Intel code. (Nor do I know of any such program available elsewhere.)

Since an app bundle doesn't contain the original source code of the app, you also can't use it to recompile the source code for the simulator.

Comment: Is this now still valid in 2023 given M1/M2 macs? Is it now possible?

Comment: It might be possible with Herculean effort, but you’d have to at least fix up the executable’s load commands to point to the simulator’s libraries instead of device libraries.